# Facebook Connect / Pass User's name to database for storage

Tags: php, javascript, database, facebook

I am using the Facebook Connect API to connect to FB from my web page, share a specified link and then thank them via an alert message. What I'm missing is the ability to grab the poster's username and save it in my database. The reason for this is because I'm using it to enter everyone that shares the link into a prize draw so I need to keep track of who's doing it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <title>Facebook Share Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'REMOVED-FOR-SECURITY',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true
          });


          FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'I\'ve Got Kids!',
    link: 'http://ivegotkids.com',
    picture: 'http://ivegotkids.com/wp-content/themes/thepink/images/logo.png',
    caption: 'Parents Supporting Parents',
    description: 'I just registered at I\'ve Got Kids, a unique support site. From pregnancy to grandparenthood, there\'s something for everyone. I\'m sure you\'ll find something on IGKs to interest you! Click the link and register for free.'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');



    } else {
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    alert(response.name +', Thank you for sharing. You will now be entered into our prize draw for a free lifetime membership.');
        });
    }
  }
);
        };

        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));
      </script>

    </body>
 </html>
```

I have switched the alert around in the final step for testing purposes only as I don't want to be posting something to my wall a hundred times whilst I'm testing it so the message currently only outputs when the post is cancelled rather than when it is sent.

What I need to do now is grab the poster's username and save it in my database. I can get the user's name by using the FB.API call like I have done in the alert at the end but I just don't know how to pass this along to my database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You are aware that the user should allow your app first, right? check [FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)

Comment: The user is already prompted to sign in if they are not logged in to facebook already and once they are signed in, they get to preview the post and publish it themselves. I had a look at FB.Login and I added this to the above code and once I did, it opened up the facebook login box (when I wasn't logged in) three times!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are collecting the data in javascript, you will need to use an AJAX call to save the data. One way is to create page that can save the data and have your javascript post the data to that file.

Look at my AJAX post on my blog to see how I often do it.
http://sullivan.net/blog/tag/ajax/